# Re-receive email in outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, azure, inbox

I'm using an Azure logic app to process emails on an inbox. The trigger is set to fire whenever an email is received. This is working fine. The issue is if there is an error somewhere along the way, we want to re-process the email. We can accomplish this in a number of ways, but by far the simplest would be to just put the email back in the inbox and have it pick the email up again.

I've attempted many combinations of the instructions outlined here: https://www.msoutlook.info/question/218 and got it to work once. And haven't been able to replicate it since. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Edit to clarify my actual question: How can I get my Logic App to pick up the email again? Can this be done by simply moving the email back into the inbox or something similar? When the email is processed, it gets moved to a subfolder of the inbox and marked as read. I've attempted to mark it as unread put it back into the inbox as suggested by the above link, but to no avail. I have not been able to find further literature on the subject.

Comment: Why not gracefully handle the error(s)? You haven't really included any details about how you do your processing. What you do to pickup a mail from the inbox or what happens to it. With what you have provided just resend the mail to your automation inbox. Your question doesn't even contain a question?

Comment: Gracefully handling the errors is definitely part of the plan, but we're still building out the scope of what this process is going to handle so it's hard to plan for all the possibilities. In the meantime, when an email fails to process we need some way to run it through the system again without asking the client to re-send their email. I've updated the question, hopefully it is more clear now.

Comment: Why would you not include your actual trigger? The [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-workflow-actions-triggers) already has various examples on mail and it might be important how you actually set it up to figure out what makes it trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What we ended up doing was splitting the logic app into two pieces. One that listened to the mail box and one that did the actual processing (named it "..._Core"). The logic app that listened to the mailbox would then call the _Core logic app. In the case of errors, the _Core would send those emails to a "Failed" folder. To actually re-run those emails, we have another logic app that triggers when an email is flagged. When triggered, it would send those emails to the _Core app again, where it would either run successfully or end up right back in the "Failed" folder. This made debugging a simple process of 1) make edits to _Core, 2) flag the email, repeat if necessary.

As far as I can tell what I was asking for in this question is not possible.